# Make a thumbnail with PIL, enhanced way

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I know there is a thumbnail method in PIL. What I want to make differently is how it resizes the original image. Assume I have a 300x360px vertical image. I want to resize it to a constrained box that is 150x100px horizontal image. So I need to find the smallest side of the original image, resize to it, and then crop the rest to the center from the largest side.
How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
from PIL import Image

width = 150
height = 100
infile = Image.open(in_filename)
im = infile.copy()

if im.size[0] >= im.size[1]:
    im = im.resize((height * im.size[0]/im.size[1], height))
    im = im.crop(((im.size[0] - width)/2, 0, (im.size[0] + width)/2, height))
else:
    im = im.resize((width, width * im.size[1]/im.size[0]))
    im = im.crop((0, (im.size[1] - height)/2, width, (im.size[1] + height)/2))

im.save(out_filename)
```

There might be a faster way to do this, but this should work.

Comment: It's not exactly that. There is supposed to be four case. Your example won't work with let say `width=100, height=100`